# Minimum cost matrix java

Tags: java, android, matrix

Hi I am trying to calculate minimum cost for matrix example 2 and there is getting output but example one is not getting output.

The total cost of a path is the sum of the integers in each of the visited cells. The solution needs
to handle grids of various sizes with a minimum of 1 row and 5 columns up to 10 rows and 100
columns. If in the next move, the total cost will exceed 50, that path is abandoned.

The purpose of this challenge is to find the path of least cost (that is, the path with the lowest
total cost of any possible path). The paths of least cost through two slightly different 5 x 6 grids
are shown below. The grid values differ only in the bottom row. The path for the grid on the
right takes advantage of the adjacency between the first and last rows.

But out showing wrong only on first example .It was showing

```
Yes
18
121222
```

but i need output like `Yes 16  123445`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findPath();
    }

    private void findPath() {
        TextView txtMatrixDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_display);

        // 1st example
        int[][] matrix1 = new int[][]{
                { 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 6 },
                { 6, 1, 8, 2, 7, 4 },
                { 5, 9, 3, 9, 9, 5 },
                { 8, 4, 1, 3, 2, 6 },
                { 3, 7, 2, 8, 6, 4 } };

        String txtMatrix1 = "";
        for(int i=0; i<matrix1.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matrix1[0].length; j++){
                txtMatrix1 += matrix1[i][j] + " ";
            }
            txtMatrix1 += "\n";
        }
        txtMatrixDisplay.setText(txtMatrix1);

        Solution firstExample = new Solution();
        firstExample.Path(matrix1);
        String result1 = "\n";
        if(firstExample.getStat()){
            result1 += "Yes\n";
        } else {
            result1 += "No\n";
        }

        result1 += firstExample.getCost() + "\n";
        result1 += firstExample.getPath() + "\n";
        txtMatrixDisplay.append(result1);

        // 2nd example
        int[][] matrix2 = new int[][]{
                {3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 6 },
                {6, 1, 8, 2, 7, 4 },
                {5, 9, 3, 9, 9, 5 },
                {8, 4, 1, 3, 2, 6 },
                {3, 7, 2, 1, 2, 3 } };

        String txtMatrix2 = "\n";
        for(int i=0; i<matrix2.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matrix2[0].length; j++){
                txtMatrix2 += matrix2[i][j] + " ";
            }
            txtMatrix2 += "\n";
        }
        txtMatrixDisplay.append(txtMatrix2);

        Solution secondExample = new Solution();
        secondExample.Path(matrix2);
        String result2 = "\n";
        if(secondExample.getStat()){
            result2 += "Yes\n";
        } else {
            result2 += "No\n";
        }

        result2 += secondExample.getCost() + "\n";
        result2 += secondExample.getPath() + "\n";
        txtMatrixDisplay.append(result2);

        // 1st example
        int[][] matrix3 = new int[][]{
                {19, 10, 19, 10, 19 },
                {21, 23, 20, 19, 12 },
                {20, 12, 20, 11, 10 } };

        String txtMatrix3 = "\n";
        for(int i=0; i<matrix3.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matrix3[0].length; j++){
                txtMatrix3 += matrix3[i][j] + " ";
            }
            txtMatrix3 += "\n";
        }
        txtMatrixDisplay.append(txtMatrix3);

        Solution thirdExample = new Solution();
        thirdExample.Path(matrix3);
        String result3 = "\n";
        if(thirdExample.getStat()){
            result3 += "Yes\n";
        } else {
            result3 += "No\n";
        }

        result3 += thirdExample.getCost() + "\n";
        result3 += thirdExample.getPath();
        txtMatrixDisplay.append(result3);
    }
}
```